# How to install java in RancherOs

Tags: docker, rancher

can anyone tell me how I can install and run java in Rancher OS. 
I want to link the java with other docker running containers. 
If I run a docker container how I will do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "install" Java, you run a container that has Java in it, such as the official library image  (https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) or your own image based off of it.

Comment: I tried to run java docker container and ran successfully. But I want to set this java path to run another application (docker running container). how can I do this?